# Как преобразовать код с интерфейсом на Python для использования с .ui файлом (Qt Designer)?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtabwidget

Все примеры с использованием *PyQt5* написаны с инициализацией интерфейса на *Python*. 
Как правильно преобразовывать его на использование с **.ui** файлом? 
Например из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581549/fading-on-tab-change-in-pyqt) код для затухания при смене вкладки в `QTabWidget`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class FaderWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pixmap_opacity = None
        self.timeline = QTimeLine(333, self)
        self.timeline.valueChanged.connect(self.animate)
        self.timeline.finished.connect(self.close)

    def start(self, old_widget, new_widget):
        self.pixmap_opacity = 1.0
        self.old_pixmap = QPixmap(new_widget.size())
        old_widget.render(self.old_pixmap)

        self.timeline.start()

        self.resize(new_widget.size())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap_opacity:
            QWidget.paintEvent(self, event)
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setOpacity(self.pixmap_opacity)
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.old_pixmap)

    def animate(self, value):
        self.pixmap_opacity = 1.0 - value
        self.update()


class FaderTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.currentChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndex)
        self.last = -1
        self.current = self.currentIndex()

    def onCurrentIndex(self, index):
        self.last = self.current
        self.current = self.currentIndex()
        if self.widget(self.last):
            self.widget(self.last).setCurrentIndex(1)
            old_widget = self.widget(self.last).widget(0)
            current_widget = self.widget(self.current).widget(0)
            fade = self.widget(self.current).widget(1)
            fade.start(old_widget, current_widget)

    def addTab(self, widget, text):
        stack = QStackedWidget(self)
        stack.addWidget(widget)
        fade = FaderWidget(self)
        fade.timeline.finished.connect(lambda: stack.setCurrentIndex(0))
        stack.addWidget(fade)
        stack.setCurrentIndex(0 if self.currentIndex() == -1 else 1)
        QTabWidget.addTab(self, stack, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QWidget()

    tabWidget = FaderTabWidget()
    tabWidget.addTab(QCalendarWidget(), "Tab1")
    editor = QTextEdit()
    editor.setPlainText("Hello world! " * 100)
    tabWidget.addTab(editor, "Tab2")
    layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
    layout.addWidget(tabWidget)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Как данный код адаптировать под использование с **.ui** файлом? 
И можно ли будет по аналогии так делать с другими элементами: кнопками, текстовыми полями и т.д.

---

Моя попытка совместить код (неправильная и нерабочая):

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('fading.ui', self)

        self.tabWidget = FaderTabWidget()

        self.tabWidget.addTab(QCalendarWidget(), "Tab3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(QTextEdit(), "Tab4")


class FaderWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pixmap_opacity = None
        self.timeline = QTimeLine(333, self)
        self.timeline.valueChanged.connect(self.animate)
        self.timeline.finished.connect(self.close)

    def start(self, old_widget, new_widget):
        self.pixmap_opacity = 1.0
        self.old_pixmap = QPixmap(new_widget.size())
        old_widget.render(self.old_pixmap)

        self.timeline.start()

        self.resize(new_widget.size())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap_opacity:
            QWidget.paintEvent(self, event)
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setOpacity(self.pixmap_opacity)
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.old_pixmap)

    def animate(self, value):
        self.pixmap_opacity = 1.0 - value
        self.update()


class FaderTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.currentChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndex)
        self.last = -1
        self.current = self.currentIndex()

    def onCurrentIndex(self, index):
        self.last = self.current
        self.current = self.currentIndex()
        if self.widget(self.last):
            self.widget(self.last).setCurrentIndex(1)
            old_widget = self.widget(self.last).widget(0)
            current_widget = self.widget(self.current).widget(0)
            fade = self.widget(self.current).widget(1)
            fade.start(old_widget, current_widget)

    def addTab(self, widget, text):
        stack = QStackedWidget(self)
        stack.addWidget(widget)
        fade = FaderWidget(self)
        fade.timeline.finished.connect(lambda: stack.setCurrentIndex(0))
        stack.addWidget(fade)
        stack.setCurrentIndex(0 if self.currentIndex() == -1 else 1)
        QTabWidget.addTab(self, stack, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**fading.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>691</width>
    <height>488</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QCalendarWidget" name="calendarWidget"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
          <property name="plainText">
           <string>Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! </string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>691</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код можно адаптировать следующим образом:

- встраиваем виджет `FaderTabWidget` в форму *Qt Designer*.
  Подробно как это делается уже публиковалось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаем **fading.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>691</width>
    <height>488</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="FaderTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>1</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QCalendarWidget" name="calendarWidget"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
          <property name="plainText">
           <string>Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! </string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>691</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>FaderTabWidget</class>
   <extends>QTabWidget</extends>
   <header>fadertabwidget</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

- конвертируем **`pyuic5 fading.ui -o fading_ui.py -x`**

**fading_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(691, 488)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.tabWidget = FaderTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.tab)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! "))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


from fadertabwidget import FaderTabWidget                 # !!!
```

- создаем модуль **fadertabwidget.py**

---

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class FaderWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pixmap_opacity = None
        self.timeline = QTimeLine(333, self)
        self.timeline.valueChanged.connect(self.animate)
        self.timeline.finished.connect(self.close)

    def start(self, old_widget, new_widget):
        self.pixmap_opacity = 1.0
        self.old_pixmap = QPixmap(new_widget.size())
        old_widget.render(self.old_pixmap)

        self.timeline.start()

        self.resize(new_widget.size())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap_opacity:
            QWidget.paintEvent(self, event)
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setOpacity(self.pixmap_opacity)
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.old_pixmap)

    def animate(self, value):
        self.pixmap_opacity = 1.0 - value
        self.update()


class FaderTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.currentChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndex)
        self.last = -1
        self.current = self.currentIndex()

    def onCurrentIndex(self, index):
        self.last = self.current
        self.current = self.currentIndex()
        if self.widget(self.last):
            self.widget(self.last).setCurrentIndex(1)
            old_widget = self.widget(self.last).widget(0)
            current_widget = self.widget(self.current).widget(0)
            fade = self.widget(self.current).widget(1)
            fade.start(old_widget, current_widget)

    def addTab(self, widget, text):
        stack = QStackedWidget(self)
        stack.addWidget(widget)
        fade = FaderWidget(self)
        fade.timeline.finished.connect(lambda: stack.setCurrentIndex(0))
        stack.addWidget(fade)
        stack.setCurrentIndex(0 if self.currentIndex() == -1 else 1)
        QTabWidget.addTab(self, stack, text)
```

- создаем модуль **main.py**

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from fading_ui import Ui_MainWindow                                  # +++


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                            # +++ Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
#        uic.loadUi('fading.ui', self)                               # ---
        self.setupUi(self)                                           # +++
        
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(0, "Tab 1")                        # +
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(1, "Tab 2")                        # +

#        self.tabWidget = FaderTabWidget()                           # ---

        self.tabWidget.addTab(QCalendarWidget(), "Tab3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(QTextEdit('Hello World'), "Tab4")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]